# want to open text file in some text editor programmatically in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, text-editor

I want to open a text file into some text editor say notepad programmatically in c/c++.

Also i want to see real time updation of text into that text file while opening in a editor.

Please suggest.

Comment: Do you mean that the file on disk should continually mirror what's being written in notepad?

Comment: What will the user be doing with the editor?  Just using it to see what the file currently is?

Answer (score 3):

Most editors accepts the path of the file-to-be-opened as 1st argument. E.g.

```
notepad.exe c:/foo.txt
```

Just execute it as a shell/runtime command in your program.

Comment: In windows: `_spawnlp(_P_NOWAIT, "notepad.exe", "c:\\foo.txt", 0);`

Comment: In C and C++: system("notepad.exe c:\\foo.txt");

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something as simple as monitoring a log file, you want a unix program called "tail", or its [Windows equivalent](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/).

It will give you a simple Notepad-like Window which displays the contents of a log file in (more or less) real time.

Having the editor (notepad, tail, whatever) continually monitor the file for changes isn't your job as the C++ developer, it's up to the program.

Answer (score 0):

To get the file to open in the default application specified, try this (C#):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("text.txt");
```

To specify an application, try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "notepad.exe", "text.txt");
```

I'm not aware of any way to handle real time updation of the file in the editor however.

Comment: The question was not about C#

Answer (score 0):

To see real time update in your editor window try to find editor's window handle (you may use [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) function). Insert text in the editor's textfield or reread it from the file and call [RedrawWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms913080.aspx) after that. However calling it after each letter could give some nasty flickering if the text come from a program.

Answer (score 0):

After you have it running, see above. you can possibly keep the file updated using SendMessage from the Windows API and sending Ctrl+S(save) to the notepad window.